# How does Windows Task Scheduler know when to execute the next action?

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I have a task setup with Windows Task Scheduler in Windows 7.  It has 3 actions.  The first action runs a program, but that program window remains open after the action.  Unfortunately, this somehow prevents the 2nd action from executing.  If I manually close the program window from action 1, then action 2 executes.  Is there any way I can get action 2 to execute without requiring that action 1 close its window?  Additionally, how exactly does the task scheduler know when action 1 has been completed?

Also, when I run the set of actions in the command prompt it actually runs as expected.  However, when run as a scheduled task, action 1 will hang until its dialog window is closed.

Comment: What is action 1? Is it a batch file? An exe? What OS are you running?

Comment: action 1 is a tortoise svn update, but I'd like to leave the update window open after execution.  action 2 is running a phpunit test in the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell more about what tasks are you executing? You can find more help here, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308558. Can also do a command line check using "schtasks /query /fo LIST /v"

Are action 2 and 3 separate scheduled tasks? I guess not. Why don't you make all the actions into one script and use command line to update the code (so it doesn't open a window and hence gives you back exit code for the task, success/fail)

Comment: I'm just trying to update a checked out working copy of some code and then trying to run a unit test suite afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You must be running a 9x version of windows. Right Click on the file you're running as `action 1`, click on `properties` then `Program` tab, and put a check mark on `Close on exit`.

[image: pif]

Comment: James, thx for the reply.  However, I'd like to leave the window open upon completion.